# How to use local Docker image with testcontainers?

Tags: java, docker, testcontainers

I want to use a local-only Docker image with [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/).

The code looks like this:

```
new GenericContainer("rserver:latest")...
```

However it looks like another image with same name is fetched from a remote registry.

How can I force testcontainers to use a local image?

Comment: Try tagging your local images? `docker build -t local/rserver`, and use that

Comment: Maybe not use `latest` but the version of your local image?

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks. Using another name as workaround does the job. I'm still wondering if using a local image could be enforced.

Comment: @Ben Wouldn't specifying the version only reduce the chance that an unwanted images gets fetched?

Answer (score 7):

I know this answer is too late but it can be useful for others who has exactly the same issue.

If you are already have the image you want, try to implicitly set the image Pull Policy for your container to default:

```
GenericContainer container = new GenericContainer("someImage")
        .withImagePullPolicy(PullPolicy.defaultPolicy());
```

The default image Pull Policy tells the Docker to pull the image from a remote repository only if it does not exist locally.

Note that this method (withImagePullPolicy(..)) is available only with latest versions of TestContainers dependency. I use 1.14.3.

Comment: PullPolicy.defaultPolicy() did not work. Still pulls from github which fails their limit parameters.